# Python Minidom modify/append content files

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Since 8 hours I'm now trying to parse a XML and add 5 lines of text into the xml. I'm making really no progress and neither writexml, toxml nor saveXML seems to work from the minidom lib

We want to parse the xml and add some lines before the closing  Tag. Sounds easy?

So my situation is:
A File called updates.xml

> ```
> <UpdateSite>
>    <SomeTags></SomeTags>
>    <SomeTags2></SomeTags2>
>    <SomeTags3></SomeTags3>
>
>    <SomeTags></SomeTags>
>    <SomeTags2></SomeTags2>
>    <SomeTags3></SomeTags3>
>
>    <SomeTags></SomeTags>
>    <SomeTags2></SomeTags2>
>    <SomeTags3></SomeTags3>
> </UpdateSite>
> ```

What we are doing:

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("updates.xml")
updateSite=dom.getElementsByTagName('UpdateSite')
updateSite.append('<SomeTags>')
updateSite.append("<product>xx.xxxxxx.xxx</product>")
updateSite.append("<version style=\\"eclipse\\">"+$cleanVersion+"</version>")
updateSite.append("<resource style=\\"executable\\">SomeURL</resource>)
updateSite.append("</update>")
dom.saveXML(self, updateSite)
dom.writeXML(self, file_handle)
dom.toxml(self)
```

updateSite contains the correct new lines, but the file just isn't updated. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Parse the document, get `UpdateSite` node, append a `Text` node to it. Then pass an opened file to the `dom.writexml()`:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, Text

dom = parse("updates.xml")

updateSite = dom.getElementsByTagName('UpdateSite')[0]
text = Text()
text.data = 'test'
updateSite.appendChild(text)

with open("new_updates.xml", "wb") as f:
    dom.writexml(f)
```

produces the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><UpdateSite>
   <SomeTags/>
   <SomeTags2/>
   <SomeTags3/>

   <SomeTags/>
   <SomeTags2/>
   <SomeTags3/>

   <SomeTags/>
   <SomeTags2/>
   <SomeTags3/>
test</UpdateSite>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: We want to write into the same file as we have read, is that possible?

Comment: @byemute sure, just change the name from `new_updates.xml` to `updates.xml`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. Gave up for now, I'm so frustrated^^

Comment: Just Tested it out, it's not working. Nothing is written to the file.

Comment: @byemute hm, it works for me. are you running the exact same piece of code I've provided?